# heapq: What is an elegant way to use customized priority key with associated data that are not comparable?

Tags: python, priority-queue, heapq

As shown in [a basic example in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html#basic-examples), one can always use a tuple so that the first element is compared as the priority key. However, what if the associated data are not comparable? What would be an elegant way to resolve this?

For example,

```
import heapq
h = [(3, 2), (4, 3)]
heapq.heapify(h)
heapq.heappush(h, (3, (0, 1)))
```

This emits

```
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()
```

Comment: Do what the example does: put a unique count into the tuple after the priority, so that the data items themselves will never need to be compared.

Comment: @PM2Ring The uniqueness cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Why not? Create a simple generator (eg use itertools.count), and whenever you create a tuple to put on the heap call that generator to get a new number.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry I misunderstood you. Your solution would work, but I'm seeking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: It looks elegant enough to me. ;) And it's essentially the same strategy that `heapq.merge` uses, as you can see in [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b2ecb8b486d85d11ee7b523dfd2c76b2820bbe83/Lib/heapq.py#L314).

Comment: @PM2Ring OK.. I guess that's the best way to do. Thanks anyway.